# HTTP ERROR: 503 ... accessing /jenkins. Reason: Service Unavailable

Tags: continuous-integration, jetty, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy **Jenkins** in **Jetty**'s /webapps. I've copied jenkins.war to this directory, restarted Jetty, but when I point to http://localhost:8080/jenkins, the system warn:

**HTTP ERROR: 503 Problem accessing /jenkins. Reason: Service Unavailable**

Here is my console log

```
2012-02-02 09:13:39.912:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@22bbe7: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator@1985384 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@22bbe7
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator@1985384 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@22bbe7
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.setConfiguration(FormAuthenticator.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
2012-02-02 09:13:39.913:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@16ef3b1: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator@1985384 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@22bbe7
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator@1985384 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@22bbe7
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.setConfiguration(FormAuthenticator.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
2012-02-02 09:13:39.914:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/jenkins,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins.war-_jenkins-any-/webapp/},/home/ic/jetty/webapps/jenkins.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator@1985384 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@22bbe7
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.setConfiguration(FormAuthenticator.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
...

2012-02-02 09:13:41.235:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this same error when trying to install Jenkins in a new (8.1.X) instance of Jetty.  It appears that there was [bug fix](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368773) that may have introduced this behavior and it's exhibited when installing Jenkins/Hudson.  A security realm/loginservice is now required to be given explicitly.

In environments without strict Jetty security requirements, ie: non-Jetty enthusiast who just want to get Jenkins up and running.  Create a context file, `$JETTY_HOME\contexts\jenkins.xml`, that contains a security handler.

```xml
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/jenkins</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/jenkins.war</Set>

  <Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
            <Set name="name">Jenkins Realm</Set>
            <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
  </Get>

</Configure>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a better answer as it provides the path where to put the XML.

Comment: Also check http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-12-04-install-jenkins-1-4-with-jetty-9

Answer (score 2):

To use the sample test JAAS module included with Jetty:

```xml
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/jenkins</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/jenkins.war</Set>
  <Set name="securityHandler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
     <Set name="loginService">
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
         <Set name="name">Test JAAS Realm</Set>
         <Set name="loginModuleName">xyz</Set>
       </New>
     </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

This then point to the realm and definitions in `etc/login.conf` and `etc/login.properties` respectively.

Following this example it should be relatively easy to get your own JAAS module set up.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty is configured to use Java Authentication and Authorization Services (JAAS). The security is defined in realm (username + roles).

Basically, all you have to do, is to tell Jetty to use defines security for deployed `jenkins.war` file. The most easy way is to create a `jenkins.xml` file and put it in same folder as `jenkins.war` file.

The contents of the file are (for Jetty 9):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/jenkins</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/jenkins.war</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
  <Set name="securityHandler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
     <Set name="loginService">
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
         <Set name="name">Test JAAS Realm</Set>
         <Set name="loginModuleName">xyz</Set>
       </New>
     </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I got the same issues. Previously installed using jenkins repo

**Removed Jenkins**

- yum remove jenkins && yum clean all

**got the latest rpm**

- wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.7.4-1.1.noarch.rpm
- rpm -ivh jenkins-2.7.4-1.1.noarch.rpm
- service jenkins start

Everything started perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I had switched to openjdk-1.7, but did not have the 'devel' package installed. Switching to IBM's solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that if you've started getting this error recently, and think you may have used an AJP reverse proxy, it's possible you've been quietly updated to Jenkins 2.x which breaks that.

Luckily it's an easy fix if you're on Apache 2.4 now - you can use an HTTP reverse proxy instead as [described here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache).

I wrote a bit more background on this in [this post](http://noellh.com/blog/jenkins-2-apache-503-service-unavailable/).